# Hide xfoil pop-out window

Tags: window

I'm running a program (concretely xfoil) and during calculations it opens and closes a window automatically. I would like the pop-up window to keep hidden.

Create control file:

```
cat <<EOF > controlfile.xfoil
NACA 0012
GDES
Flap0.8 0.0425 0.1
eXec

OPER
RE 1388888
MACH0.0561930287789
v
ITER
300
ALFA 10
FMOM 0.8 0.0425

QUIT
EOF
```

Run file from terminal and save output:

```
xfoil < controlfile.xfoil >outputfile.out
```

When running it you'll see briefly a pop-up window.

How can I keep the pop-up window hidden? Luckily the source code of xfoil is available and I could compile a version without the window, but I would prefer not having to.

Comment: I ran into exactly the same problem. Thank you for asking this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit excessive, but you can start a 2nd X11 server with no framebuffer and direct your display there:

```
Xvfb :1 &
sleep 2
DISPLAY=:1 xfoil <controlfile.xfoil >outputfile.out
kill -15 $!
```

Comment: Why is `sleep 2` necessary?

Comment: 2 is an arbitrary number, you may need more or less. The problem is you have to wait for `Xvfb` to run far enough for it to create the socket needed by `xfoil` to connect to. To avoid all problems you should really run a small loop, doing `sleep 1` and then checking if `Xvfb` is ready, eg with `if DISPLAY=:1 xdpyinfo >/dev/null`...

Comment: Is there anything special to consider when using this from a bash script? When I run these commands from the command line, then everything works fine. However, when I put those commands into a script, then I get the error `xdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":99"`.

Comment: @FelixCrazzolara Sorry, I don't know why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a top menu in XFoil called plotting options, which you can access with PLOP. Then the command G F for graphic output : false will disable these pop-ups.

So in your program that would be the addition of:

PLOP
G F

At the very beginning. Don't forget the empty line so that you go back to top menu !

Comment: Just to be clear, this only prevents the XFOIL display window itself from opening. On my MacOS computer, it still keeps opening an empty pop-up dock icon (with no XFOIL display). This pop-up steals focus, which is the really annoying thing. The answer by @meuh solves the complete problem, though it's pretty hacky!